# Why do inline scripts block rendering when put at the bottom of a page?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, browser, rendering

I  read [High Performance Web Sites: Essential Knowledge for Front-End Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309) and in it the author suggests that all JavaScript code should be externalized and put at the bottom of the page instead of putting it in the head.

This is illustrated in [this example](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/move-scripts.php). The **external** script tag blocks both **downloading** and **progressive rendering** of a page, so the solution was to put it at the bottom of the page.

However, in his second book [Even Faster Web Sites: Performance Best Practices for Web Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522304) he talks about **Inline** JavaScript tags.

Inline scripts also blocks downloading and rendering of a page, so he suggests moving them also to the bottom of the page. However, this acts still blocks the rendering of the page entirely as illustrated in [this example](http://stevesouders.com/efws/inline-scripts-bottom.php)

Why do moving external scripts to the bottom of the page lets the page render progressively while moving inline scripts blocks rendering completely till the script is executed?

---

PS:

**The question isn't about why add JavaScript to the bottom of the page instead of putting them in the head. It's about why bottom inline scripts block rendering while bottom external scripts don't.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the inline script, the time is taken up running the script, which might change the DOM. Trying to render the DOM while it's mutating is a recipe for a mess. So rendering only happens at points when the JS is stalled, and therefore the DOM is stable.

While waiting for an external script to download, the running of scripts is stalled, so the DOM can be rendered safely. The downloaded JS won't be run until the rendering is complete.

Comment: Interesting, so if I have an external script followed by an inline script and both are put in the bottom of the body, the inline script will have wait for the external script to be downloaded and executed first. That way the page will not render till both scripts have been executed, correct?

Comment: No. The browser may render the DOM while stalled waiting for the external script to download. At that point, it won't even (logically) be aware of the presence of the inline script in the mark-up because the parser hasn't reached it yet. Note that the external script could include a `document.write()` call that could stop the inline script from being interpreted as a script at all.

Comment: I tested what you said and it's true, but in case the external files weren't cached. The page rendered and didn't wait for the inline script the first time I opened it, but on subsequent requests the external file was already cached so rendering was halted till the inline script finished. BTW I'm using a custom inline script that takes 6 mins to finish for testing purposes.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that if you dynamically add script tags to the page, that IE (and not chrome) does that async, which is contra to behavior when you load script tags in the head tag, obviously.